# Is there any real distinction between a ring and wondrous item?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

In 3.5 edition (and Pathfinder), there was a distinction between rings and wondrous items, including in part that there were distinctions within wondrous items, including what applied to various body parts and slotless items.  Though I see rings remain classified as "rings" and not "wondrous items" in 5th edition, I can't locate any particular rule that identifies why there's a distinction.  (The only rule that guides magic items appears to be attunement and realism regarding body parts.)  So, is there a reason that there remains a distinction between these types of magic items, or is this a remnant from older editions of the game?

Comment: Are you asking about the mechanical distinctions (i.e. if/how this distinction affects the rules) or are you asking why the designers decided to keep them distinct in 5e? If the latter then unfortunately [designer intent questions are off-topic here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7964/14878). If the former then what problem are you trying to solve with this question? Why do you want to know? Have you come across a situation where this actually matters? It would help to include more information about what situation caused you to ask this question.

Comment: My question is based on whether there are mechanical distinctions.

Comment: Then to reiterate Purple Monkey; what problem are you trying to solve with this question? Why do you want to know? Have you come across a situation where this actually matters? It would help to include more information about what situation caused you to ask this question.

Comment: Those who play 5e and haven't played 3.5 could do with this question explaining how ring and wonderous item were ever the same. It makes no sense to me at all. Are you saying that all rings in 3.5 were also classified as wonderous items, or that all wonderous items were rings? Were there no mundane rings? How did people get married?!

Comment: @SeriousBri As regards your last sentence: they get married by using the first level spell *Ceremony* from Xanathar's. They save their ring money for those expensive *warding bond* spell requirements. 

Answer (score 5):

#### The only difference is that rings are worn on fingers.

As per *Dungeon Master's Guide* p.139-141, rings tend to be rare and have powerful or special abilities, and must normally be worn on a finger or similar digit. Most other worn items are categorized as wondrous items.

There's no rule difference other than the manner in which they're worn. It's not like D&D 3.5 where you needed different item creation feats or could only wear two rings at a time. D&D 5e lets you wear as many rings as your DM allows, and the magic item creation rules (e.g. *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* p.129) don't differentiate by type, only by rarity. If you look at the rings in *Dungeon Master's Guide* p.189-193, they're often rare or legendary, but not always.

Essentially, 5e is just duplicating the magic item categorization used by D&D 3.5, but the game no longer uses any of the rules which differentiated rings from wondrous items.

Answer (score 3):

**The only to point is to differentiate sources**

In 5E you can never benefit from the more than one of a particular bonus coming from the same source. If you had two rings of protection you can't gain any benefit from wearing both at the same time. However, a ring of protection and a cloak of protection will stack. So rings are just another category of magical item in order to allow certain bonuses to be stacked.

Comment: @Odo Yes, but that is my main point. They just divide things up into different categories to allow stacking. You could have two rings that give AC bonuses, they just need to be named different. But generally speaking you don't see many items of the same type that give the same bonus.